# github actions not modifing files

Tags: git, sed, github-actions

I'm trying to bump via github workflow the project version.
Via workflow I give the version I want to release and then I get the last tag and substitute the string inside the 'pyproject.tom;' file using sed and then commiting the file

The actions runs but does not change the file
What's wrong?

```
 - name: Bump version 
    run: |
      export TAG=$(git tag --sort version:refname | tail -n1)
      echo ${TAG}
      export version=$(cut -c 2- <<< $TAG)
      echo ${version}
      sed -i 's/${version}/${{ github.event.inputs.version }}/' pyproject.toml


  - name: Commit changelog and manifest files
    id: make-commit
    run: |
      git add CHANGELOG.md  pyproject.toml
      git commit --message "Prepare release v${{ github.event.inputs.version }}"

      echo "::set-output name=commit::$(git rev-parse HEAD)"


  - name: Push new branch
    run: git push origin release/v${{ github.event.inputs.version }}
```

Comment: you probably need to *push* the changes up, just as you would with any other commit to the github repo.  It might make sense to think of the worker running on "github's copy" of the repo, but that's not how github/actions work:  to access the repo contents, actions do a clone just like you

Comment: nope is not that.. Following those 2 steps there is also a push one.. and the pyproject.toml is not modified..but the changelog is (that I also change with a previous action not listed here). so the issue I would say is with the sed command? or something else.. as the file does not change.

Comment: add a `git diff` command then and make sure your `sed` command is actually making the change you want

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

```
  - name: Bump version in package.json
    shell: bash
    env:
      TAG: ${{ steps.previoustag.outputs.tag }}
    run: |
      echo "$TAG"
      version=$(cut -c 2- <<< $TAG)
      echo $version
      sed -i "s/$version/${{ github.event.inputs.version }}/" pyproject.toml
      git diff

  - name: Commit changelog and manifest files
    id: make-commit
    run: |
      git add CHANGELOG.md pyproject.toml
      git commit --message "Prepare release v${{ github.event.inputs.version }}"

      echo "::set-output name=commit::$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```